# How to parallel AFNetworking request and process response in sequence with Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, afnetworking, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to fetch JSON data from 5 different URLs. The network requests can be performed in parallel, though the responses have to be processed in a certain order. In addition, I also want to have a single point of error handling logic.

The code I'm having right now is like the following. The problem is, only the subscription of `signalFive` and `signalSix` has been invoked. The `subscribeNext` block for all the other signals has never been invoked. I suspect the problem is because the subscription happens after the `sendNext` occurs.

Is there a better/standard way to perform this kind of request?

```
- (RACSubject *)signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:(NSString *)remotePath
{
    RACSubject *signal = [RACSubject subject];

    [self.requestOperationManager GET:remotePath parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        for (id obj in responseObject) {
            [signal sendNext:obj];
        }
        [signal sendCompleted];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [signal sendError:error];
    }];

    return signal;
}

FMDatabase *db = [SomeDatabase defaultDatabase];
[db beginTransaction];

RACSubject *singalOne = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_ONE_PATH]];
RACSubject *singalTwo = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_TWO_PATH]];
RACSubject *singalThree = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_THREE_PATH]];
RACSubject *singalFour = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_FOUR_PATH]];
RACSubject *singalFive = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_FIVE_PATH]];
RACSubject *singalSix = [self signalForFetchingFromRemotePath:[self urlStringWithPath:SYNC_SIX_PATH]];
RACSignal *combined = [RACSignal merge:@[singalOne, singalTwo, singalThree, singalFour, singalFive, singalSix]];

[combined subscribeError:^(NSError *error){
   [db rollback];
}];

[singalFive subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
  [ClassE save:dict];
} completed:^{
   [singalSix subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
       [ClassF save:dict];
   } completed:^{
       [singalOne subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict){
           [ClassA save:dict];
       } completed:^{
           [singalTwo subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict){
               [ClassB save:dict];
           } completed:^{
               [singalThree subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
                   [ClassC save:dict];
               } completed:^{
                   [singalFour subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *dict){
                       [ClassD save:dict];
                   } completed:^{
                       NSLog(@"Completed");

                       [db commit];
                   }];
               }];
           }];
       }];
   }];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to enforce a specific order, use `+concat:` instead of `+merge:`.

On its own, concatenation means that the requests will *not* be performed in parallel. If you want to recover that behavior, you can use `-replay` on each signal (to start it immediately) before passing it to `+concat:`.

As an aside, nested subscriptions are almost always an anti-pattern. There's usually a built-in operator to do what you want instead.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the answer. The reason I don't use `+concat:` is because for each signal, the `dict` should be converted into different class instance. I have update the question to reflect this problem.

Comment: @GregWang Then use `-map:` or `-flattenMap:` on each signal before passing it into `+concat:`. The principle remains the same.

Comment: I'm afraid that still not meeting what I wish to accomplish. Here is the solution that I use after all kinds of experiment. Instead of `RACSubject`, I create the singal with `[RACSignal startEagerlyWithScheduler:... block:...]`. Thus the signal will start the `request` but will cache all the `dict`s in the scheduler until someone subscribe to the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `combineLatest`:

```
NSArray *signals = @[singalOne, singalTwo, singalThree, singalFour, singalFive, singalSix];
[[RACSignal combineLatest:signals] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *values) {
  // All your values are here
} error:^(NSError *error) {
  // error
}];
```